# Proguard with AAR library issue

Tags: android, android-proguard, aar

I have a android library with one class and I want to make it an .aar library. When I set `minifyEnabled` to true, another android project cannot use the library (It is fine if `minifyEnabled` is set to false). I would like to ask what is the correct configuration of proguard with AAR library

**HelloWorld.java**

```
package com.example.hello;

import android.util.Log;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void Hello(){
        Log.v("HelloWorld","Hello World!");
    }
}
```

**build.grandle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
}
```

**proguard-rules.pro**

```
-dontwarn android.support.v7.**
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }

-keep class com.example.hello {public *;}
```

Comment: Can you try changing the last line in proguard-rules to `-keep class com.example.hello.** {public *;}`

Comment: @basilisk It seems to work but is it normal that it can still be decompiled by android studio? Also, is that the correct way to handle dependencies library?

Comment: @Joshua Any APK can be decompiled. Proguard does not protect an APK or library in any way. It performs just a little bit obfuscation for classes that don't belong to the API.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try changing the last line in proguard-rules to

```
-keep class com.example.hello.** {public *;}
```

As for Android Studio being able to decompile, you can't prevent that. If you want to protect your code, I suppose the best you can do is to obfuscate most of it, and then extend the desired functionality through interfaces that you do not obfuscate by adding the relevant proguard rules.

Comment: i tried this solution + the proguard from original question. i am getting a weird behaviour when i use the resulting aar file, some of my aar objects are giving "Cannot resolve symbol" error. BUT it is compiling correctly.

Comment: Two asterisks don't compile anymore. Any other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Any APK can be decompiled. Proguard just makes the decompiled codes more difficult to understand